# Where can I get Remastersys?

Tags: downloads, deb, remastersys

I have been wanting to make a customized re-distributable distro for my LUG for a while, and just came across the info on Remastersys.

Looks perfect, but the site is no longer in existence.  I've seen mention of the .deb to get it in places, but can't find that either.

I saw Relinux as an alternative, also no longer a project, and then found Black Lab Image Creator ($50.00 "donation" to get it....is it really a donation if you can't get an use the software without paying?)

Anyway.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Again, not trying to make a full distro, just want to customize one for our LUG.

Thanks

Comment: IMO there is no shortcut to learning how to build a custom .iso. I highly suggest the debian-live scripts. There is a steep learning curve, but, once you understand the process the debian live scripts generate a nice , clean, custom .iso. The graphical tools (remastersys and similar) do not make such nice .iso . Remasersys is no longer maintained and as far as I know the old .deb would not work with modern versions of ubuntu. http://live-systems.org/

Comment: I appreciate the info, and eventually I may want to fully build my own .iso, but right now, I'm just looking for something fairly simple.   I'll check out the debian live scripts though, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this repository](https://launchpad.net/~mutse-young/+archive/ubuntu/remastersys).

Download
[this](https://launchpad.net/~mutse-young/+archive/ubuntu/remastersys/+files/remastersys_3.0.5-1~trusty1_all.deb)
and
[this](https://launchpad.net/~mutse-young/+archive/ubuntu/remastersys/+files/remastersys-gtk_3.0.5-1~trusty1_all.deb)
package then open terminal
and type
`sudo dpkg -i`
and drag and drop the file `remastersys_3.0.5-1~trusty1_all.deb` on the terminal, then press enter in terminal
provide your password.

After that is installed 
`sudo dpkg -i`
and drag and drop on the terminal the file `remastersys-gtk_3.0.5-1~trusty1_all.deb`
provide your password
then in your menu you'll find Remastersys

Answer (score 0):

remastersys is not maintained, use Pinguy Builder

http://pinguyos.com/2015/09/pinguy-builder-an-app-to-backupremix-buntu/

Comment: This is very cool looking.  Thanks for the link.